# Text editor with revision functionality (win32)

Tags: text-editors

I need a text editor which can save to its own format, storing change-by-change, character-by-character revisions, and possibly playing them back. Do you know any offline app with this capability?

The revision functionality already exists in [Etherpad](http://etherpad.com/), an online collaborative editor. I need a similar, but offline app.

Comment: windows, linux, mac?

Answer (score 1):

vim has a pretty large undo and redo buffer - You can undo any number of changes (I'm unsure what the limit is) and redo them. Does that do what you want?

Update:

Persistent undo is like a local version control system that you don't have to manage.
To set it up simply put this in your .vimrc:

> set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
>   set undofile
>   set undolevels = 1000 "maximum number of changes that can be undone
>   set undoreload = 10000 "maximum number lines to save for undo on a buffer reload

To get more help simply type:

> :help new-persistent-undo

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with any text editor out there, even plain old notepad, by using it in conjunction with revision control software like SVN.  Some text editors, like Notepad++, have support such software included either directly or via plugin.

Comment: Using SVN I would have to save and check in at every character change. I am looking for an automated way of character-by-character revisions and possibly a time slider.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything that saves character-by-character revisions to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think [e-texteditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com) provides this functionality through the personal revision branches:

> http://e-texteditor.com/blog/2006/making-undo-usable

[image]